Why iframe post message returns NOT ALLOWED(405 Error)?
I need to implement facade to interact parent-child and child-parent (where child is iframe)
Here is my Web Config of parent:
<location path="~/default/default.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>

IFrame it is just a popup to cummunicate with
How I integrate iframe:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#iframeModal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width:600,
        height: 500, 
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
 });
 
    $("#openAIDialog").click(function () {
        $("#iframeModal").dialog("open");
    });
             
    function sendMessageToIframe(message) {
        let iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
                 if (iframe && iframe.contentWindow) {
                   iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
                 } else {
                   console.error("Iframe not available");
                 }
             }  
             
             function receiveMessageFromIframe(callback) {
                let iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
                window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
                   // Add more specific checks if necessary, like verifying the event.origin
                   if (event.source === iframe.contentWindow) {
                     callback(event.data);
                   }
                 });
               }
               
              window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
                  if (event.origin !== 'http://localhost:81') {
                    return;
                  }
                  console.log(event.data);
              }, false);
         });
...
<div id="iframeModal" style="width: 100%;height:100%" title="AI Assistant">
 <iframe style="width: 100%;height:100%" src="http://localhost:81"></iframe>
</div>

And my iframe is on docker. It is just a dummy server with form
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="script.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Dummy Server</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="" method="POST">
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

 window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {

  console.log('Message received from parent:', event.data);

  if (event.data.type === 'GREETING') {
    alert(event.data.payload);
  }
});

const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(window.parent);

  window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({message: "Hello from iframe"}), "http://localhost:57967");
});

I tryed to disable CORS, to specify destination URL

"Why iframe post message returns NOT ALLOWED(405 Error)?" - it didn't. postMessage happens in the browser, there is no actual POST HTTP request involved - but the error message you get, implies that this is an HTTP error message, with status code 405, METHOD NOT ALLOWED. And the reason for that is that you did nothing to suppress the default action of your submit button - so it submits the form to the current URL, with method POST, but apparently that endpoint does not accept POST requests.

@JaromandaX It is perfectly possible to start from the parent page. document.getElementByTagName(‘iframe’)[0].postMessage()
